# I need vertical align, horizontal scrollable and not moving to bottom

Tags: html, css

I need vertical-align, horizontal scrollable and not moving to the next row.

That's how it looks now https://prnt.sc/pxutz9

```css
.twoPaneHeader {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.twoPaneHeader {
 height: 300px;
   width: 33%;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='telefonsitabletaWDS sliderHeader'>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle; border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"><h3> Resurse pentru jocurile tale preferate</h3><p>Încercăm să punem bazele unei biblioteci de resurse gratuite</p><p><a href="https://warsn.ro/forum/staffapplications/application/1-aplic%C4%83-pentru-uploader/">Ne poți ajuta aplicând pentru Uploader</a></p></div>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle; border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1)"><h3> Căutăm moderatori (oferim recompensă)</h3><p>Dacă consideri că ai abilitățile necesare pentru a modera un forum</p><p>poți face o cerere <a href="">aici</a></p></div>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle;"><h3> Începuturile pot fi grele</h3><p><a href="https://warsn.ro/forum/faq/">Citește lista noastră de întrebări recente</a></p></div>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle;"><h3> Începuturile pot fi grele</h3><p><a href="https://warsn.ro/forum/faq/">Citește lista noastră de întrebări recente</a></p></div>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle;"><h3> Începuturile pot fi grele</h3><p><a href="https://warsn.ro/forum/faq/">Citește lista noastră de întrebări recente</a></p></div>
    <div class="twoPaneHeader" style="position: relative; vertical-align: middle;"><h3> Începuturile pot fi grele</h3><p><a href="https://warsn.ro/forum/faq/">Citește lista noastră de întrebări recente</a></p></div>
    
          </div>
```

Comment: for clarity, you meant that you need the container "telefonsitabletaWDS" to scroll horizonrally keeping the content in the same row?